# How could I set the staring and ending points randomly in a grid that generates random obstacles?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, random

I built a `grid` that generates `random obstacles` for pathfinding algorithm, but with `fixed starting and ending points` as shown in my snippet below:

```
import random
import numpy as np

#grid format
# 0 = navigable space
# 1 = occupied space

x = [[random.uniform(0,1) for i in range(50)]for j in range(50)]
grid = np.array([[0 for i in range(len(x[0]))]for j in range(len(x))])

for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(x[0])):
        if x[i][j] <= 0.7:
            grid[i][j] = 0
        else:
            grid[i][j] = 1


init = [5,5]       #Start location 
goal = [45,45]     #Our goal 

# clear starting and end point of potential obstacles
def clear_grid(grid, x, y):
    if x != 0 and y != 0:
        grid[x-1:x+2,y-1:y+2]=0
    elif x == 0 and y != 0:
        grid[x:x+2,y-1:y+2]=0
    elif x != 0 and y == 0:
        grid[x-1:x+2,y:y+2]=0
    elif x ==0 and y == 0:
        grid[x:x+2,y:y+2]=0

clear_grid(grid, init[0], init[1])
clear_grid(grid, goal[0], goal[1])
```

I need to generate also the `starting and ending points randomly` every time I run the code instead of making them fixed. How could I make it? Any assistance, please?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace,

```
init = [5,5]       #Start location 
goal = [45,45]     #Our goal
```

with,

```
init = np.random.randint(0, high = 49, size = 2)
goal = np.random.randint(0, high = 49, size = 2)
```

Assuming your grid goes from `0-49` on each axis. Personally I would add grid size variables, `i_length` & `j_length`

**EDIT #1**

```
i_length = 50
j_length = 50
x = [[random.uniform(0,1) for i in range(i_length)]for j in range(j_length)]
grid = np.array([[0 for i in range(i_length)]for j in range(j_length)])
```

Comment: Yeah, it works dear, but after your permission, what do 0, 49, and 2 mean? and How could I do this i_length and j_length?

Comment: `0` to `49` is the length of your grid in the `i` & `j` directions, the `2` is the number of integers you are asking `np.random.randint()` to return see [docs here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html). Also see edit to answer

Comment: yeah use `print("init: ", init, " goal: ", goal)` pretty basic stuff considering the code you've already written

Comment: thank you so much dear. :) Forgive me, from a lot of reading I feel my brain is not working.